# Automatically move file from one bucket to another bucket and make public in Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two bucket in Amazon S3. one bucket **mail.example1.com** and it is used by Amazon SES to store **email raw file**. I have another bucket **example2.com** with two folder. One is **files** for storing files and another is **mail folder**. I want when a mail will store in **mail.example1.com** bucket, it will automatically move to **mail folder in example2.com bucket** and it excess will be **public**.

I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Set example2.com bucket policy for public access and if you want manual replication form example1.com to example2.com  execute below command.

aws s3 sync s3://example1.com s3://example2.com

or if you want it to be automated go with Lambda functions.

Comment: AWS CLI works but it just copy file from one bucket to another and it is not automated. I want this process automated and file will be move not copy. Can you give example of Lambda function to do this job. Thanks in advance.